# How to get actual data/content provided by NSItemProvider rather than the type

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

I am new to iOS 11 Drag and Drop feature. I know how to load a particular type of object when dropped in view that can accept that type of object. However, before calling the `loadObject(ofClass:completionHandler:)`, I want to know the values that the dropped item is holding.

In my `dropInteraction(_:performDrop:)` delegate method, when I try to get the description of the itemProvider object, I only get the type-

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {

        if let itemProvider = session.items.last?.itemProvider{
            print("item provider \(itemProvider.description)")
        }
}
```

As I was dropping an image from safari, the above code printed-

```
item provider <UIItemProvider: 0x600000c43640> {types = (
    "public.jpeg",
    "public.url"
)}
```

Here I can't see the url value. If I want to get the url value, I have to do-

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {

    session.items.last?.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self, completionHandler: { itemProvider, err in
      if let urlItemProvider = itemProvider{
          print("url = \(urlItemProvider.absoluteString)")
      }
  })
}
```

Basically whenever an image is dropped, I want to save its associated url and the details about the image in a custom class before I attempt to load it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems like you've figured it out

Comment: like the content types of the ItemProvider, is there any way to get the associated value of those types?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what `loadObject(ofClass:completionHandler:)` is doing?

Comment: for loadObject, I am explicitly asking for a particular class. On top of this I am attempting to load the resource. I want to save the resource and based on some condition I will load that resource. That's why, I don't want to call loadObject(ofClass:completionHandler:) unless I really want to work with that particular resource.However, after quite some digging, I figured, there may not be any alternative way.

Comment: I forgot about this, and I presume you solved your problem by now. The issue is that there is a many-to-many relationship between type identifiers, and `NSItemProviderReading` classes (see [`NSItemProviderReading.readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemproviderreading). This means that given a type identifier, there is no "sensible default" class to handle it, because there are multiple equally valid classes that could be used, depending on the circumstance. That's why you're explicitly asked for the class you want.

Answer (score 1):

I found that loading two objects with the loadObject method always resulted in an error. However, duplicating the itemProvider with the `.copy()` method worked.

For example:

```swift
let provider = item.dragItem.itemProvider.copy() as! NSItemProvider
item.dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self, completionHandler: { (url, _) in
    provider.loadObject(ofClass: String.self) { (data, error) in
    }
})
```